# How to use Windows Azure CDN with existing ASP.NET webforms application?

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, cdn, azure-cdn

I have an ASP.NET Web Application on Azure and want to move my static content - images, CSS to the Azure CDN.

I have over 100 image files being used throughout the application stored in a folder "App_Themes/img" ...

In what way, can I minimize the effort in the move?

My current steps would be ...
- Manually upload all files to cdn ..
- Manually change all urls to the cdn (using Ctrl-H, but still is time-intensive and not error free)
- Somehow manage the testing locally... (Add some code at every page to use a baseurl, depending on debug or release) ...

Is there any way that I could add a new route, etc so that I don't have to manually change the urls, as well as move between file-system urls and CDN to develop the application locally and deploy it.

Thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was added a config entry in the web.config:

and replaced path `/App_Themes/SpringDoctor/images/` with `<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesPath"]%>`

And upload all images to the appropriate blob.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this via IIS URL rewriting or move static content into a /cdn folder, I haven't tested this but Maarten Balliauw has a great blog post on how serve content from the CDN. ["Using the Windows Azure Content Delivery Network"](http://acloudyplace.com/2012/04/using-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network/)